# Is it possible to overlay 3D objects onto views in an Android app using Bullet/LibGDX?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, libgdx, bulletphysics

I've been trying to accomplish this with Unity. I have been able to integrate a Unity project into an Android project (e.g. tap an Android button and the Unity content loads in a new activity), but what I want is to have the 3D objects of my Unity content displayed with the Android views behind/underneath them.

I thought I was on track to accomplishing this but I discovered that the technique I was using is invalid for Unity 4.3 and up, which is what I have. This is apparently due to refactoring of the UnityPlayer class, which now no longer supports GLSurfaceView. I saw a post from a Unity dev saying that there was serious bugs when using alpha in the framebuffer, or some such, so I don't think it's possible to do at all any more.

So, to save me potentially wasting my time attempting this with Bullet/LibGDX, can anyone tell me if it's even possible to do it?